# abort a script when a file is missing

Tags: bash, file

I have 3 types of files and they are loaded into a database in the sequence below:

```
Shipments - File frcrgxxxx.txt
Invoices - File frnfsxxxx.txt
Invoices Items - File fritsxxxx.txt
```

where xxxx can be any number e.g.: 7834

For example, `frcrg7834.txt`, `frnfs7834.txt` and `frits7834.txt` are one set.
we have hundreds of files coming in everyday. If 1, 2 or all of the 3 files in a set is missing the script should stop there.

Let's say the below files are in the processing folder:

```
frcrg7834.txt, frcrg7835.txt, frcrg7836.txt,
frnfs7834.txt,                frnfs7836.txt,
frits7834.txt, frits7835.txt, frits7836.txt
```

Only the set `frcrg7834.txt`, `frnfs7834.txt`, `frits7834.txt` should be loaded because the file `frnfs7835.txt` is missing from the second set [`frcrg7835.txt`, `frits7835.txt`] and the script should stop there, even though set 3 [`frcrg7836.txt`, `frits7836.txt`, `frnfs7836.txt`] is available.

In the above scenario if any of the 7834 files are missing then no files should be loaded.

Comment: Please format your question to improve readability. And which is the language you are using?

Comment: i need a unix script to do the above

Comment: Would Perl be ok? Or does it have to be bash?

Comment: i need bash script please

Comment: You forgot to ask a question in the body of the question.  You've not specified what should happen to the files after they've been processed.  You've not specified how the program knows which sets have already been processed.  You've not showed what code you've tried and explained where you've got problems.  (And, as a design for the real world, holding up new entries because one older entry is missing one of the files is probably a bad idea; however, that's tangential to the 'how to' issues that should be being asked.)

Answer (score 1):

As you say all three files could be missing, you will have to define which sets you expect - in this case passed on to the script as parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash 

FIRST_SET=$1
LAST_SET=$2

DIR=dir

for set in $(seq $FIRST_SET $LAST_SET)
do
    for type in "fcrg" "frnfs" "frits"
    do
        if [ ! -r $DIR/${type}${set}.txt ]
        then
            echo "found incomplete set $set - exiting"
            exit 2
        fi
    done
done

# do_something
```

Comment: The `continue 2` should be either `break 2` or `exit 1`; processing should stop.  Probably, the 7842 and 8000 should be `$1` and `$2` — parameterize the script so it knows what to process.

Comment: Okay, the question changed meanwhile

Comment: It was mostly formatting that changed rather than the substance, but the formatting makes it possible to read the substance.

Answer (score 0):

You can exit a loop with the `break` command.

You can exit a script with the `exit` command.

Either is a reasonable way of stopping processing — which is better depends on context (for example, is there cleanup work to do).  Make sure you report the error appropriately so people know why the script is no longer processing anything.